# how to change method signature using bytebuddy?

Tags: java, agent, byte-buddy

is bytebuddy able to add a parameter to the existing method? I mean when I am instrumenting the class I would like to add parameters dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [`Transformer`](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/Transformer.java) when you match a method in the transformation DSL. This way, you can change any attributes. If you add a parameter, do however notice that no call site of this method will continue to work as the signature has changed, normally, this is not recommended and often there are other ways of achieving what you are trying to do. If you added more detail to your question, maybe I can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if I update the original method signature :

`void f(int x)` to `void f(int x, String y)`